# How can I return an amount sum grouped by date and ID using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I want return the data in an object of type `IQueryable<Money>`, and the money table in the database keeps a record of money transactions (buy/sell) for several customers each time a buy or sell occurs it saves the date and the amount and I get this data using a repository as follows:

```
ID                 Value        Action         Date 
1                  12             Buy          1/2/2018
1                  -5             Sell         1/2/2018 
1                  7              Buy          1/2/2018 
1                  3              Buy          1/2/2018

2                  35             Buy          1/2/2018
2                  -27            Sell         1/2/2018 
2                  20             Buy          1/2/2018 

4                  20              Buy         1/2/2018
4                  30              Buy         1/2/2018
4                  -50             Sell        1/2/2018 

1                  15              Buy         12/10/2017
1                  -23             Sell        12/10/2017 
1                  20              Buy         30/10/2017 
1                  3               Buy         30/10/2017
```

In my C# code I want to display the total buy and sell amounts per day for each customer (sum(buy) sum(sell) group by date and customer ID) using LINQ and EF, and display the value in a grid, as follows:

```
ID                Buy Value       Sell Value         Date 
1                  22                 -5              1/2/2018
1                  15                 -23             12/10/2017
1                  23                  -              30/10/2017
2                  55                 -27             1/2/2018 
4                  50                 -50             1/2/2018
```

I am not sure if this is possible to do from the code or it's better to create a view for it.

What I have tried so far:

```
public List<Money> GetData(MoneyFilter filter)
{
    var data = _moneyRepository.GetFiltered(filter);

    List<MoneyDto> list = new List<MoneyDto>();

    foreach (var item in data.GroupBy(x => new {x.Date,x.ContactId}))
    {
        list.Add(new MoneyInOutFlowDto
        {
            Sell = item.Sum(x => x.Amount<0?x.Amount:0),
            Buy = item.Sum(x => x.Amount>0?x.Amount:0),
            Id = item.ContactId,
            Date = item.Date
        });
    }
    return list;
}

public class MoneyDto 
{
    public int ContactId {get;set;}
    public decimal Sell {get;set;}
    public decimal Buy {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}        
}
```

Comment: Well, the question will reside in the use case.  Should the database be doing all the work since this facet of information is required throughout your organization? Your company workflow stores these in the database?  Or should the application be doing the transformation of a raw domain model of the represented data?

Comment: @maccettura please check my question again.

Comment: @Greg it's the latter, the application must do the data transformation and show it in the view

Comment: you are grouping by `x.Date,x.ContactId` how can you access `item.Id` ? it is not part of the group by

Comment: shouldn't `item.Id` be `item.ContactId` ?

Comment: you are also adding`MoneyInOutFlowDto` object inside `MoneyDto` collection. Are they sharing a relationship(inheritance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started off well by grouping but the selection was not implemented correctly

```
var data = _moneyRepository.GetFiltered(filter);

List<MoneyDto> list = data.GroupBy(_ => new { _.Date, _.ContactId })
    .Select(g => new MoneyDto {
        ContactId = g.Key.ContactId,
        Date = g.Key.Date,
        Sell = g.Where(_ => _.Action == "Sell").Sum(_ => _.Amount),
        Buy = g.Where(_ => _.Action == "Buy").Sum(_ => _.Amount),
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = _moneyRepository.GetFiltered(filter);

data.GroupBy(x => new { x.Action, x.Id }).Sum(x => x.Value).Select(x => new MoneyDto{
//Here assign the values
Id = .xId //and the other values
}).ToList();
```